# JSF composite component, multiple value fields

Tags: jsf, composite-component

Is it possible to have multiple values for a composite component.  here is the example of what I want to be able to do:

```
<foo:zipcode id="zipcode" value="#{bean.zipcode}" city="#{bean.city}" >
    <f:ajax eventt="changeEvent" update="city">
</foo:zipcode>
<h:inputText id="city" value="#{bean.city} />
```

Where the composite component has an input for the zipcode.  Once entered I do a lookup/validation of the zipcode and update the city.

The composite component looks like:

```
<cc:interface componentType="component.zipCode">
    <cc:attribute name="value" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="city" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <p:inputText id="zipCode" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" >
        <p:ajax partialSubmit="true" process="@this" update="@this" listener="#{cc.lookupZip}"/>
    </p:inputText>
</cc:implementation>
```

Then for the backing component I have:

```
@FacesComponent(value = "component.zipCode")
public class UIZipCode extends UIInput implements NamingContainer {
    public void lookupZip(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        // Code to lookup zipcode and get city.
        // What goes HERE to update the city passed as attribute?
    }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious.  I've dug through tons of BalusC's posts and tried something like:

```
ValueExpression city = (ValueExpression) getAttributes().get("city");                
city.setValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), cityString);
```

I have most of this working, but can't figure out how to set the value of city in the backing bean from the lookupZip method. The value of city is always
 null.  Is this possible?

Comment: The last two lines of code you posted look (sort of) ok. Does it not work? fail? throw an error?

Comment: The problem is that city is always null.  I've tried putting type="javax.el.ValueExpression" into the cc:attribute tag, but that didn't help. I have also tested the backing bean value by passing it to a value in a p:inputText field and it works fine.  I have also tested that I can get regular string attributes using the getAttributes.  Just not sure how to get hold of a valueExpression that I can then set the value on.  Curious, what does sort-of mean, am I going about this in some "code smell" fashion?